# $.post adds double backslashes

Tags: php, jquery

I use jQuery to send data from the client to the server and to store data in my database. Now I use the $.post-function from jQuery. I use it like the following

```
var queryUpd = "UPDATE settings SET round_duration='10'"
$.post("../../server/test.php", {func: "manipulate", query: queryUpd}, function(json,    textStatus) 
 {
alert(json); //Outputs UPDATE settings SET round_duration =\\\'10\\\'           
 });
```

The php funcion "test.php" is simple:

```
<?php
  echo json_encode($_POST["query"]);  //send values to the client
?>
```

As you can see, the php-function gets an invalid query, since it adds two backslashes in front of the \'. So why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have MAGIC_QUOTES enabled?

Comment: Note that this is a huge security hole.

Comment: Passing SQL from Javascript to the server is an unspeakably bad idea.

Comment: have you tried adding `json_encode(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["query"]))`

Comment: Do you really run SQL commands straight from your javascript?

Comment: I generate the SQL-commands in Javascript and send them to the server. The server executes it and sends it back to the client. Why is that so bad?

Comment: @enne87: `{function: "manipulate", query: 'DROP DATABASE DATABASE();'}`. Boom goes your database, boom goes your site.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I don't know about that... I kind of like the idea of being to able to remotely utterly nuke sitesthat I don't like...

Comment: This is the grandmother of SQL injection holes.

Comment: Ok Marc, so it would be better to send just the values to the server and there generate the sql-statements, right?

Comment: Exactly, and make sure to use parameters, or it won't help.  Always imagine what an enemy could do by reading your Javascript.

Comment: Note that numbers don't need to be quoted anyway, so you could just remove the quotes in this case.

Comment: You mean just with UPDATE settings SET round_duration=10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's php, then try somewhere in the bootstrap of your application

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify that what you're getting back is JSON.  Otherwise, jQuery guesses, and sometimes it's wrong:

```
$.post("../../server/test.php", {func: "manipulate", query: queryUpd}, function(json,    textStatus) 
     {
    alert(json); //Outputs UPDATE settings SET round_duration =\\\'10\\\'           
     },"json");
```

The comments on your original post are correct, however.  You shouldn't send queries through ajax.  You should send form data, and create queries based on that data, after checking it to make sure it's valid.

Comment: Ok but the string that I send to the server is definitely wrong, otherwise it would execute my query.

Comment: Why would it execute your query?  The only thing test.php does is encode the query in JSON and send it back.

Comment: Yes now at the moment, but actually there is code that makes executes this query. It works on my local machine but not at the remote server.

Comment: If it's a dev to live issue, then it's probably something different in the PHP config of the live server.  But I still say the server side code should be creating queries.  Otherwise what's to stop me from posting "DROP TABLE settings" to your php page?  (http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You are right of course Dave, unfortunately I don't have the time now to change the code so I hope you'll be nice to me and don't drop my table :) Thanks in advance.